# Using Union All with Multiple Sub Queries to return Total

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, dataset

I have a query that pulls various daily statistics for the day.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT     e.Location_Name AS Location, c.customers AS Customers, '$' + CONVERT(nvarchar, CAST(c.net_sales AS money), 1) AS Sales, '$' + CONVERT(nvarchar, 
           CAST(e.Ticket_Goal AS Decimal(10, 2))) AS [TKT Goal], '$' + CONVERT(nvarchar, c.Ticket_avg) AS TKT, CAST(d.Labor_Hours / c.customers AS Decimal(10, 2)) 
           AS Labor, CONVERT(nvarchar, CAST(d.Labor_Dollars / c.net_sales * 100 AS Decimal(10, 1))) + '%' AS [%]
FROM         (SELECT Store_Number, SUM(Net_Sales) AS net_sales, SUM(Customers ) AS Customers , CAST(SUM(Net_Sales) / SUM(Customers ) AS decimal(10, 2)) 
                                              AS Ticket_avg
                       FROM  daily_sales_tb AS a
                       WHERE (Operations_Day = DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
                       GROUP BY Store_Number) AS c INNER JOIN
                          (SELECT     Store_Number, SUM(Labor_Hours) + SUM(Overtime_Labor_Hours) AS Labor_Hours, SUM(Labor_Dollars) + SUM(Overtime_Labor_Dollars) 
                                                   AS Labor_Dollars
                            FROM          daily_labor_tb AS b
                            WHERE      (Operations_Day = DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
                            GROUP BY Store_Number) AS d ON c.Store_Number = d.Store_Number INNER JOIN
                          (SELECT     Store_Number, Ticket_Goal, Location_Name
                            FROM          dds.Location_Table_Info_Tb) AS e ON c.Store_Number = e.Store_Number
```

Here is the output:

```
Location       Customers      Sales    TKT Goal   TKT   Labor   %
1                 100        $1000      $9.00     $10     1.2  20%
2                 200        $1500      $9.00     $7.50   1.3  15%
3                 300        $2000      $9.00     $6.67   1.4  20%
4                 100        $800       $9.00     $8      1.1  20%
```

Here is what I'd like the output to look like (add a total line):

```
 Location            Customers      Sales    TKT Goal   TKT   Labor   %
    1                 100        $1,000      $9.00     $10     1.2  20%
    2                 200        $1,500      $9.00     $7.50   1.3  15%
    3                 300        $2,000      $9.00     $6.67   1.4  20%
    4                 100        $800        $9.00     $8      1.1  20%
   TOTAL:             900        $5,300       -        $5.89    -    -
```

I have attempted to use a Union All -

```
SELECT     e.Location_Name AS Location, c.customers AS Customers, '$' + CONVERT(nvarchar, CAST(c.net_sales AS money), 1) AS Sales, '$' + CONVERT(nvarchar, 
                      CAST(e.Ticket_Goal AS Decimal(10, 2))) AS [TKT Goal], '$' + CONVERT(nvarchar, c.Ticket_avg) AS TKT, CAST(d.Labor_Hours / c.customersAS Decimal(10, 2)) 
                      AS Labor, CONVERT(nvarchar, CAST(d.Labor_Dollars / c.net_sales * 100 AS Decimal(10, 1))) + '%' AS [%]
FROM         (SELECT     Store_Number, SUM(Net_Sales) AS net_sales, SUM(Customers ) AS Customers , CAST(SUM(Net_Sales) / SUM(Customers ) AS decimal(10, 2)) 
                                              AS Ticket_avg
                       FROM          daily_sales_tb AS a
                       WHERE      (Operations_Day = DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
                       GROUP BY Store_Number) AS c INNER JOIN
                          (SELECT     Store_Number, SUM(Labor_Hours) + SUM(Overtime_Labor_Hours) AS Labor_Hours, SUM(Labor_Dollars) + SUM(Overtime_Labor_Dollars) 
                                                   AS Labor_Dollars
                            FROM          daily_labor_tb AS b
                            WHERE      (Operations_Day = DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
                            GROUP BY Store_Number) AS d ON c.Store_Number = d.Store_Number INNER JOIN
                          (SELECT     Store_Number, Ticket_Goal, Location_Name
                            FROM          dds.Location_Table_Info_Tb) AS e ON c.Store_Number = e.Store_Number

                            UNION ALL
                            select 'TOTAL:', SUM(Customers ), '$' + Convert(nvarchar,Cast(SUM (net_sales) as money),1), '-', Convert(nvarchar,CAST(SUM(Net_Sales) / SUM(Customers ) AS money)), '-', convert(nvarchar,'-')
                            from daily_sales_tb
```

When I run this query, i'm getting an SQL Error:

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.
```

How can I fix this to output the data correctly?

I'm running this query in vb.net, populating a dataset, then converting the dataset to a HTML table.  Once the conversion is done, I email the table as the body of an email.

Comment: Doesn't SQL Server have ROLLUP or similar, that can be used instead of that UNION ALL?

Comment: You really should be doing most of that display stuff in your display layer (whatever your front end is).

Comment: I'm using vb.net - However, i'm converting the dataset to an HTML Table, and emailing it out.  Adding it in-between isn't a great option.

Comment: The error is because you are trying to mix datatypes in your first column. You will need to convert your first column to varchar for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `CAST(d.Labor_Hours / c.customers AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Labor` in your first select and `'-'` in your Union.. Just convert `Labor` to NVARCHAR like you are the rest of the values in the main select

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the query is trying to convert the text 'TOTAL:' to a number.  It does so to match the prior queries that have 'Store_Number' in that column.  To fix, try converting 'Store_Number' to a character type:

Change This:

```
SELECT     Store_Number
```

To This:

```
SELECT     Convert(nvarchar,Store_Number) as Store_Number,
```

Comment: are you referring to the first select in the main query "Location" or are you referring to the sub-queries where i'm referencing "Store_Number"  I converted the initial select of "Location_Name" and i'm still coming up with the same error.

Comment: The sub-queries.  When you perform a Union (or Union All), all of the columns need to be of the same datatype.  That is, the first column of all the queries need to have the same datatype.  The seconds all need to match, the thirds, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned the exact datatypes of the columns, the solution would be just to check these 2 things, it should resolve the error:

1. The column types before the UNION ALL should match with the column Types after the UNION ALL. This means if a column is of type Varchar, the same Varchar type should be present before and after the UNION ALL statement.
2. You may need to check the original column type of the table, the converted type you are using in the query and "make sure the field is actually convertible to the type you are trying to convert" (for eg: 'TOTAL: can be added in UNION ALL if the first column (location) is a text field, but if its an integer field, it will throw an error) - similar check needs to be done for all columns

Note: The error occurs because you are trying to convert a text field to decimal which does not have a compatible decimal value in the original field

Comment: The original query runs to completion.  As soon as the Union All query is added - is when I get the error.